# Doesnt't work(displayed) RecyclerView of List of users (android, Kotlin, RecyclerView)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, authentication, android-recyclerview

When the Application is launched after user authentification, nothing is displayed when switching to activity_main ( EXCEPT for one line of the separator of user Field name, you can scroll the activity itself)
The sourse code seems to be correct ;).

> **My MainAcivity class:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var userRecyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var userList: ArrayList<User>
private lateinit var userAdapter: UserAdapter
private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var mDbRef: DatabaseReference

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    mDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

    userList = ArrayList()


    userRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.userRecyclerView)

    userRecyclerView.run {
        userAdapter = UserAdapter(this@MainActivity, userList)
        userRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
        userRecyclerView.adapter = userAdapter
    }

    mDbRef.child("users").addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            userList.clear()
            for (postSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                val currentUser = snapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
                userList.add(currentUser!!)
            }
            userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    })
}
```

> **My UserAdapter class:**

```
class UserAdapter(private val context: Context, private val userList: ArrayList<User>):
            RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
            val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.user_layout, parent, false)
            return UserViewHolder(view)
    
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val currentUser = userList[position]
    
            holder.textName.text = currentUser.name
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount() = userList.size
    
        class UserViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val textName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name)
        }
    
    }
```

> **My activity_main.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/userRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp"

        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:listitem="@layout/user_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> **My user_layout.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2.5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_name"
        android:background="@color/orange_70"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You've posted the same layout twice - there's nothing unusual in your adapter code (give it a list that you keep a reference to, when you get data stick it in the list and tell the adapter to update) so either there's a problem with your display, or there's a problem with your data fetching. Try testing it with some dummy data (create the adapter with a list of ``User``s and see if it looks ok), and put some logging in the `onDataChange` function (or a breakpoint and debug it) to make sure you're actually getting the data you expect. Make sure your item layout's height isn't `match_parent` too

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please also add the content of your `User` class and please also respond with @AlexMamo.